# Python - Create names for dictionaries using variables from list

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the standings for a sports league. Tie breakers are based on head 2 head records. So in order to determine the team higher in the standings when a tie in points occurs I need to be able to pull head to head records between teams from a dictionary.

My plan was to create a dictionary for every team containing all their head 2 head records against other teams.

The problem is, the team names change (as well as the number of teams) from year to year. So I need to loop through the list of teams (which is called from a database) and create dictionaries for every team. Is this possible? Is there an easier way to go about this? Because I probably have no idea what I'm doing.

My code currently looks something like this:

```
wins = collections.defaultdict(int)
losses = collections.defaultdict(int)
ties = collections.defaultdict(int)
points = collections.defaultdict(int)
games_rem = collections.defaultdict(int)
poss_points = collections.defaultdict(int)

for team in team_dict:
    wins[team.shortname] = team.wins
    losses[team.shortname] = team.losses
    ties[team.shortname] = team.ties
    points[team.shortname] = team.points
    games_rem[team.shortname] = mens_games.count + team.wins + team.losses + team.ties
    poss_points[team.shortname] = team.points + games_rem[team.shortname] * 2


for team in team_dict:
    for other_teams in team_dict:
        if other_teams.shortname == team.shortname:
            continue
        vs_"string{0}".format(other_teams.shortname) = collections.defaultdict(int)
        for game in game_dict:
            if game.team1 == other_teams.shortname and game.team2 == team.shortname and game.team1score < game.team2score:
                vs_"string{0}".format(other_teams.shortname)[team.shortname] += 1
            if game.team1 == other_teams.shortname and game.team2 == team.shortname and game.team1score > game.team2score:
                vs_"string{0}".format(other_teams.shortname)[team.shortname] -= 1
            if game.team2 == other_teams.shortname and game.team1 == team.shortname and game.team2score < game.team1score:
                vs_"string{0}".format(other_teams.shortname)[team.shortname] += 1
            if game.team2 == other_teams.shortname and game.team1 == team.shortname and game.team2score > game.team1score:
                vs_"string{0}".format(other_teams.shortname)[team.shortname] -= 1
```

The issue is obviously where I try to assign the dictonaries based on team names

```
vs_"string{0}".format(other_teams.shortname) = collections.defaultdict(int)
```

I'm thinking this definitely is not allowed, but I can't think of a better way to go about this. Any ideas?

Edit:
Apologies for the poor explanation.
What I'm trying to output is a separate dictionary for every team that looks something like this:

```
vs_teamA = {'teamB': 1, 'teamC': 1, 'teamD': -1, 'teamE': 0}
vs_teamB = {'teamA': -1, 'teamC': 1, 'teamD': -1, 'teamE': 0}
vs_teamC = {'teamA': -1, 'teamB': -1, 'teamD': -1, 'teamE': 0}
vs_teamD = {'teamA': 1, 'teamB': 1, 'teamC': 1, 'teamE': 0}
vs_teamE = {'teamA': 0, 'teamB': 0, 'teamC': 0, 'teamD': 0}
```

The number would be positve if a team has a winning record vs another, and negative if they have a losing record.

Comment: can you give one example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest you is to use nested dictionary

```
In [371]: from collections import defaultdict

In [380]: match_results = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
```

## team A won team B

```
In [381]: match_results['vs_teamA']['teamB']+=1
```

## team A lost against team C

```
In [382]: match_results['vs_teamA']['teamC']+=-1
```

## team C lost against team B

```
In [383]: match_results['vs_teamC']['teamB']+=-1

In [386]: for team, games in match_results.iteritems():
   .....:     print team
   .....:     print games


vs_teamA
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'teamB': 1, 'teamC': -1})
vs_teamC
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'teamB': -1})
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I've still got some other issues with my code, but this method using nested dictionaries is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a concrete question here, but I think you could benefit learning the python module [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/). As a mini-example, look how you can organize data with a "dictionary-like" interface:

```
import pandas as pd

stat_names = "points", "games_rem", "poss_points"
team_names = "A", "B", "C"

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=stat_names, columns=team_names)

df["A"]["points"] = 30
df["B"]["points"] = 20
df["C"]["poss_points"] = 2

print df
```

Which gives

```
              A   B  C
points       30  20  0
games_rem     0   0  0
poss_points   0   0  2
```

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Hopefully it's a little more clear. That being said, the pandas module looks like it might do what I want, I'll take a look thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you consider dictionary as value?

```
{'vs_teamA': {'teamB': 1, 'teamC': 1, 'teamD': -1, 'teamE': 0},
 'vs_teamB': {'teamA': -1, 'teamC': 1, 'teamD': -1, 'teamE': 0},
 'vs_teamC': {'teamA': -1, 'teamB': -1, 'teamD': -1, 'teamE': 0},
 'vs_teamD': {'teamA': 1, 'teamB': 1, 'teamC': 1, 'teamE': 0},
 'vs_teamE': {'teamA': 0, 'teamB': 0, 'teamC': 0, 'teamD': 0}}
```